If $f \colon \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is an order isomorphism, is $f(x) + x$ also one?
If $f \colon (\mathbb{Q},\leq) \to (\mathbb{Q},\leq)$ is an order isomorphism, is the map $g \colon (\mathbb{Q},\leq) \to (\mathbb{Q},\leq)$ defined by $g(x) = f(x) + x$ also an order isomorphism? We can characterize all order isomorphisms as the closure of all rational piecewise linear functions apparently, although I have only seen this fact presented without proof.
This question was closed. In order to prevent any future discussion from being stifled, I will attempt to have it reopened.

Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Background and Motivation. We know that the statement is true for $\mathbb{R}$, because an order isomorphism $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, so $g(x)$ is continuous and by the Intermediate Value Theorem can also be shown to be surjective. Therefore, a natural question is whether this holds for $\mathbb{Q}$.
Relevant Definitions. The definition of an order isomorphism according to Wikipedia:

Formally, given two [totally ordered sets] $(S,\le_S)$ and $(T,\le_T)$, an "order isomorphism"  from $(S,\le_S)$ to $(T,\le_T)$ is a bijection $f$ from $S$ to $T$ with the property that, for every $x$ and $y$ in $S$, $x \le_S y$ if and only if $f(x)\le_T f(y)$.

Source. This is my own problem. The fact mentioned about rational piecewise linear functions can be found in Peter J. Cameron's Permutation Groups.
Possible Strategies. You could try a back-and-forth argument as done in the answer given by dialegou. Or you could try my solution which "steals" the point $0$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ with an irrational number.
My current progress. Currently, I have solved the problem.
Why is this question interesting or important? This question is an interesting riddle that I wanted to pose to MSE. As discussed before, it is related to a fact which is true over $\mathbb{R}$. At the time of this edit I think it currently has 4 upvotes (and 2 downvotes), so at least 5 people think it is interesting.

Order isomorphism is monotonic iso?

It means specifically increasing bijection, hope that clarifies it.

$\mathbb Q$ is a field....do you mean an automorphism that preserves the field structure as well as the order?  Or are you only looking at $\mathbb Q$ as an additive group?  Or maybe just a set?

No not really, please write an explicit definition. I suppose it means both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are monotonous?

Order automorphism (isomorphism) as we are in the category of totally ordered sets, this has nothing to do about the field structure.

Sorry, I will clarify. I thought it was pretty standard by the term "order isomorphism." There is a wikipedia page on it.

The term "order isomorphism" and the tag "order-theory" made the question unambiguous and the comment section much ado about nothing in my mind, FWIW.

You must put some background here, even if there is a Wikipedia page, there can be homonymes and the goal is to make the question accessible

In this forum you're expected to show some effort in order to get help. Edit your question to include your work on the problem in order to avoid your question to be downvoted and eventually closed.

Please explain exactly what your difficulty is. What happens if you (and I mean you, Sarah) work directly from the definition of order isomorphism as applied to your $f$ and $g$? What do you obtain? Where and why do you get stuck?

@PaulTanenbaum Rude much? People like you are why MSE sucks sometimes!

@SarahBrooks Stick to MO next time, I think people there are much friendlier and more reasonable.

One can construct an order automorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ recursively by a back and forth construction: Roughly, fix an enumeration $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. In the $2n th$ step make sure that $a_n$ gets send somewhere and in the odd steps make sure that $a_n$ is in the image. In each step one can continue as there are only finitely many conditions to be met. Ensure also that $\phi(a_n)\neq -a_n$. Then $\phi$ is an order automorphism, but by construction $\phi(q)+q\neq 0$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. Thus, $\phi$ is a counterexample.

Here is another answer. We know that any two unbounded countably infinite densely ordered sets are isomorphic by Cantor's isomorphism theorem. In fact, the same is true for dense colorings of such ordered sets. And the automorphism group is "highly homogeneous" so we may pre-select the image of finitely many points as well.
So, we may construct an order isomorphism $\phi \colon \mathbb{Q} [\sqrt{2}] \to \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ such that $\phi(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q}$ and $\phi(-\sqrt{2}) =+\sqrt{2}$. Now if $q$ is rational we have two cases:

If $q < -\sqrt{2}$ then $\phi(q) < \sqrt{2} < -q$, so $\phi(q) + q < 0$.
If $q > -\sqrt{2}$ then $\phi(q) > \sqrt{2} > -q$, so $\phi(q) + q > 0$.

Done!
